# Counting appearance of (a,b) as a pair in a table. (SQL)

Tags: sql

I want to count the appearance of 2 attributes as a pair. For example count the number of times A=10 and B=5 but I do not specifically know what A and B are, just any instance where they match, find how often they match. In a table that has many A values, many B values, and many values of A=10, B=5.

Essentially I want to code something that works as if COUNT((a,b)) would work. How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and *one* database tag.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Put that in a where and do a `count(*)` of matching rows. Something like

```
select count(*)
from your_table
where a = 10 and b = 5;
```

Comment: P.S.: I have a strong suspicion that this is probably not your problem at all.

Comment: Sorry I was not being specific enough, This is for if I do not know the value of A and B. If I just want to count any ones where A and B are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to count the number of instances of each permutation of `A, B` use an aggregated query:

```
select a, b , count(*)
from your_table
group by a, b
order by a, b
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I would implement, only displaying the counts where the count(*) is less than the average count(*). So for example certain a and b appears 5 times, while other permutations of a and b on average occur 10. So we display it